# Past tense and differences

Tags: difference, past-tense

Is there any difference and are they all correct?

1. It is a story that never happened!
2. It is a story never to have happened!
3. It is a story that happened not!
4. It is a story that was never to happen!
5. It is a story that didn't happen!
6. it is a story there never was!

Comment: Yes, there are differences. And while the third is not necessarily correct, it's not necessarily wrong, either. Just a bit more [archaic](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57613/what-is-the-name-for-the-grammatical-device-of-putting-not-after-a-verb-to-neg), I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are differences. To me (native speaker) they all sound weird for various reasons, and the tense is off in some of them.

It is a story that never happened!   <- **"The story didn't happen"**

It is a story never to have happened!  <- **This is wrong.**

It is a story that happened not! **<- As KSHuang say, archaic sounding as well as odd sounding like all of them**

It is a story that was never to happen!  <- **This would mean "the story that might/should have happened did not happen" - To me, it has kind of an "Alas!" feel to it. For instance "The girl was engaged and had her wedding all planned out. But it was a story that was never to happen!"**

It is a story that didn't happen! <- **Same as one - "the story didn't happen"**

it is a story there never was! <- *Makes almost zero sense to me. I think I might get what you are trying to say but no native speaker would ever write or say it like this.*

These all sound weird because a native English speaker wouldn't usually phrase a sentence like these to begin with.

I would say:

"The (or that) story never happened!" 
"But it wasn't to be" (instead of " It is a story that was never to happen!")
"The story/ That didn't happen! - in this case, it's more natural to leave the word story out altogether and just say "That didn't happen"
The best I can come up with for what you might mean by the last one is "There has never been a story like that /such a story."